# How can I change tab to "home-tab" with navbar-brand click in bootstrap 5 with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

This is my first web development project, so please pardon my lack of understanding.

I have a function Navbar() that creates a navbar on my webpage by encapsulating all elements with the navbar class. The "Logo" Button uses the navbar-brand class which creates a linked button that paths to the landing page. I am using React Router Dom to path all my pages.

To explain the code a little... I created dynamic tabs using nav-tabs class inside the navbar. It looks like this: [image]

**The problem I'm incurring** is that I'd like to have the dynamic tab over to the "Home" when the "Logo" Button is clicked.

Here the entirety of my Navbar code.

```
export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
    {/* Encapsulating <nav> tag with navbar class to build navbar using Bootstrap */}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container">

        {/* "TITLE" Button */}
        {/* Need to incorporate some event handler to switch to "Home-Tab" on click */}
        <Link class="LinkStyle" to="/">
          <div class="navbar-brand">Logo</div>
        </Link>
        
        {/* "Collapse" three-line Button*/}
        {/* triggers when screen breakpoint is met with "navbar-expand-lg" */}
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        {/* Encapsulating <div> tag with collapse class to contain desired Tabs with "Collapse" button */}
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          
          {/* <ul> tag with Dynamic Tabbed Interfaces */}
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill ms-auto" id="myTab" role="tablist">

            {/* Home Tab */}
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <Link class="LinkStyle" to="/">
                <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
              </Link>
            </li>
            
            {/* Drop Down Menu for "Services" linking to different pages */}
            {/* It is not recommended to use drop down menu in a Dynamic Tabbed interface for accessibility users. Test using voiceover and optimize.  */}
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <button class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="services-tab" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Services</button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    {/* All Services dropdown button */}
                    <li><Link to="/" class="LinkStyle">
                      <button class="dropdown-item" id="all_services-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#all-services-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-all-services" aria-selected="false">All Services</button>
                    </Link></li>

                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></hr></li>

                    {/* Service1 dropdown button */}
                    <li>
                      <Link to="/service1" class="LinkStyle">
                        <button class="dropdown-item" id="service1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#service1-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-service1" aria-selected="false">Service1</button>
                      </Link></li>

                    {/* Service2 dropdown button */}
                    <li><Link to="/service2" class="LinkStyle">
                      <button class="dropdown-item" id="service2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#service2-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-service2" aria-selected="false">Service2</button>
                    </Link></li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            
            {/* FAQs Tab */}
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <Link class="LinkStyle" to="/FAQs">
                <button class="nav-link" id="faqs-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#faqs-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="faqs" aria-selected="false">FAQs</button>
              </Link></li>
            
            {/* About Tab */}
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <Link class="LinkStyle" to="/about">
                <button class="nav-link" id="about-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#about-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="about" aria-selected="false">About</button>
              </Link></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>  

    {/* PLACE THIS CODE UNDERNEATH NAV BAR*/}
    <div class="tab-content" style={{textAlign: "center", marginTop: 50}} id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0"><h4 role="presentation">Insert Desired Home-Tab-Pane</h4></div>
      <div class="tab-pane " id="service1-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="service1-tab" tabindex="0"><h4 role="presentation">Insert Desired Service1-Tab-Pane</h4></div>
      <div class="tab-pane " id="service2-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="service2-tab" tabindex="0"><h4 role="presentation">Insert Desired Service2-Tab-Pane</h4></div>
      <div class="tab-pane " id="all-services-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-services-tab" tabindex="0"><h4 role="presentation">Insert Desired all-services-Tab-Pane (3)</h4></div>
      <div class="tab-pane " id="faqs-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="faqs-tab" tabindex="0"><h4 role="presentation">Insert Desired Faqs-Tab-Pane</h4></div>
      <div class="tab-pane " id="about-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="about-tab" tabindex="0"><h4 role="presentation">Insert Desired About-Tab-Pane</h4></div>
    </div>  
    </>
  );
}
```

On bootstrap documentation, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#via-javascript, I tried using their method to Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript.

Above my Navbar() function, I added
`const triggerEl = document.querySelector('#myTab button[data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane"]') bootstrap.Tab.getInstance(triggerEl).show() // Select tab by name`

Inside the "Logo" Button div, I thought adding id='home-tab-pane' would trigger the Home tab, but it didn't. I'm completely guessing here, so any help would be incredible. Sorry for the long, drawn out explanation. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Re-organized the navbar-brand as a child of nav-tabs, so that I am able to send data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target as shown in the code below. Although this doesn't activate the "home" tab, it routes the page and the tab-panel to the desires location on click.

The page now looks like this with further HTML/CSS customization of the navbar, tabs, and brand. [image]

```
    export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
    {/* Encapsulating <nav> tag with navbar class to build navbar using Bootstrap */}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">

      {/* <ul> tag encapsulates entire Dynamic Tabbed Interface */}
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill mx-auto" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        
        {/* "TITLE" Button encapsulated with it's own container */}
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link class="LinkStyle" to="/">
            <div class="navbar-brand" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="false">Florida Lawnscapers, LLC</div>
          </Link>
        </li>
        </div>
        
      {/* "Collapse" three-line Button*/}
      {/* triggers when screen breakpoint is met with "navbar-expand-lg" */}
      <button class="navbar-toggler my-auto mx-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
...
```